# Should I use &amp; or & in document.write?

Tags: javascript

Should I use `&` or the html entity `&amp;` in `document.write`?

```
document.write('<img src="http://www.example.com/img.jpg?a=foo&b=bar">Link</a>');
```

or

```
document.write('<img src="http://www.example.com/img.jpg?a=foo&amp;b=bar">Link</a>');
```

I've already tested it in various browsers and it doesn't seem to make any difference, but I still get requests with `&amp;` not replaced with `&` in the query string if i use the latter.

I know one should avoid `document.write` but we are not responsible for how the image tag is rendered, so we can't change it.

My previous investigations have shown that it's ok to use `&` since the browser (or document.write) escapes it with `&amp;`

Would be great if someone could explain this behaviour to me :)

tia

Comment: You shouldn't use `document.write` at all.

Comment: Naturally, this depends on the _context_ in which this line is placed. Is it inside an HTML document? Then & has to be written as `&amp;` of course. If it’s inside an external JavaScript file, then it has to be just `&`, because that is not parsed by HTML rules.

Comment: Use `&` if you see it's being properly escaped.

Comment: @VisioN thx for not reading the entire question ;-)

Comment: @reagten I have read the question, and still think that you should not use `document.write`, since you *can* insert your `<img>` element without it. Please provide the real reason why you can't insert it using `appendChild`, as an example.

Comment: @VisioN a _third party script_ requests the html tag. I only provide the  content. the _third party script_ inserts the element using `document.write`. i'm totally aware of not using `document.write` at all, I can't change it though.